# Login Blocking Users on Page

Tags: php

I want to create a script that does this: when the user writes user and password and presses Login, I want to check in the DB if he is blocked or not.

DB: ID - BLOCKED - USERNAME - EMAIL - PASSWORD - SALT

Blocked Field is boolean

So, if Blocked Field is 1, the user is Blocked and can't connect to the site, stay on Login Page.
If it is 0, he can login as a member.

Can Someone help me?

```
$block = $row['blocked'];

if(isset($_POST['username']) == $block = 1)
{   
    $login_ok = false;
    echo "Account Blocked";
} else {
    $login_ok = true;
}
```

Comment: Don't handle authentication on the client side. You're begging for trouble. It's painfully easy to hack something like what you're writing. Like `$block = 0; $login_ok = true;`

Comment: This `if(isset($_POST['username']) == $block = 1)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where is the query into the database to check if he's blocked?

Comment: are you trying to do `if(isset($_POST['username']) && $block == 1)`? Are we to assume `$row['blocked']` is your returned value from a db query?

Answer (score 0):

If the array $row represents a row that came back from the database after it has matched a username/password and you're saying $row['block'] can be 1 or 0, then you should change from this:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) == $block = 1)
```

to this:

```
if ($block)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using your `if() statement` wrong.

It should look like this:
    $block = $row['blocked'];

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && $block == 1)
{   
   $login_ok = false;
   echo "Account Blocked";
} else {
   $login_ok = true;
}
```

However if you are using `$_POST['username']` to find out if the user is blocked then your if statement can be shortened to the following:

```
 $block = $row['blocked'];

 if($block == 1)
 {   
    $login_ok = false;
    echo "Account Blocked";
 } else {
    $login_ok = true;
 }
```

Personally, using what you have there I would set it up like this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['username']){
   echo "Username not entered!";
} else {
   $username = $db->real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['username'])));
   $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
   $row = $q->fetch_assoc();

   $block = $row['blocked'];
   if($block == 1){
      $login_ok = false;
      echo "Account Blocked";
   } else {
      $login_ok = true;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps